# Deleting a node with recursion from binary search tree throws Segmentation fault in c

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to delete a node from a binary search tree that has one child. I want to delete the node using recursion. However, it does print the data but throws a `Segmentation fault` error at the value where the deletion's next value exists. I've gone through almost all of the blogs and Stack Overflow questions I can, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

- This is how my code looks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Node {
    int i;
    struct Node *leftChild;
    struct Node *rightChild;
};

struct Node *insertANodeInBST(struct Node *node, int currentValue) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        node = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        node->i = currentValue;
        node->leftChild = NULL;
        node->rightChild = NULL;
        return node;
    }

    if (currentValue == node->i) {
        return node;
    }
    if (currentValue < node->i) {
        node->leftChild = insertANodeInBST(node->leftChild, currentValue);
    }
    if (currentValue > node->i) {
        node->rightChild = insertANodeInBST(node->rightChild, currentValue);
    }
    return node;
}

struct Node *insertDataInBST(struct Node *node) {
    node = insertANodeInBST(node, 8);
    node = insertANodeInBST(node, 3);
    node = insertANodeInBST(node, 1);
    node = insertANodeInBST(node, 6);
    node = insertANodeInBST(node, 10);
    node = insertANodeInBST(node, 14);
    node = insertANodeInBST(node, 7);
    return node;
}

void inOrder(struct Node *node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    inOrder(node->leftChild);
    printf("%d ", node->i);
    inOrder(node->rightChild);
}

struct Node *searchForANode(struct Node *node, int value) {
    if (node == NULL || node->i == value) {
        return node;
    }

    if (value < node->i) {
        return searchForANode(node->leftChild, value);
    }
    if (value > node->i) {
        return searchForANode(node->rightChild, value);
    }
}


bool doesThisNodeExist(struct Node *node, int value) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    if (node->i == value) {
        return true;
    }

    if (value < node->i) {
        return doesThisNodeExist(node->leftChild, value);
    }

    if (value > node->i) {
        return doesThisNodeExist(node->rightChild, value);
    }
}

struct Node *deleteANode(struct Node *node, int value) {
    if (!doesThisNodeExist(node, value) || node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    struct Node *searchedNode = searchForANode(node, value);

    // case 1: node with no children
    if (searchedNode->leftChild == NULL && searchedNode->rightChild == NULL) {
        free(searchedNode);
        return node;
    }

    // case 2: node with a single child
    if (searchedNode->rightChild == NULL) {
        struct Node *refNode = searchedNode->leftChild;
        free(searchedNode);
        return refNode;
    } else if (searchedNode->leftChild == NULL) {
        struct Node *refNode = searchedNode->rightChild;
        free(searchedNode);
        return refNode;
    }
    return node;
}

int main() {
    struct Node *rootNode = NULL;
    printf("before deleting:");
    rootNode=insertDataInBST(rootNode);
    inOrder(rootNode);
    printf("after deleting:");
    deleteANode(rootNode,6);
    inOrder(rootNode);
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like (with a Segmentation fault):

```
before deleting:1 3 6 7 8 10 14 after deleting:1 3
```

but it should look like:

```
before deleting:1 3 6 7 8 10 14 after deleting:1 3 7 8 10 14
```

How can i fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: `deleteANode` is totally wrong and cannot possibly work, you need to rewrite it completely. Start by realizing that freeing a node without also modifying its parent is going to blow, because it creates a dangling pointer.

Comment: Ah yes, it was the leading to a dangler pointer. Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Deleting a node with recursion from binary search tree throws Segmentation fault in c

But you're *not* deleting nodes recursively.  You have some recursive auxiliary functions, but your `deleteANode()` does not call itself, neither directly nor indirectly.

That doesn't have to be a problem, but it *is* a problem for your particular code.  The main issue is that the parent node's pointer to the deleted node is never updated.  That's a task that could be supported by `deleteANode()`'s existing behavior of returning a pointer to one of the deleted node's child nodes, for in a recursive version, the caller could use the return value to update its child pointer.  But as it is, that return value is ignored. By `main()`.

Comment: Once you get that fixed you will also discover that your function does not (at all) handle the case where the node to delete has two children.

Comment: "The main issue is that the parent node's pointer to the deleted node is never updated." Yes, this was the main issue. I was getting a pointer from searchForANode(), which didn't update the node that was being returned from refNode because searchForANode() was never called again after it's searching logic, and it was leading to a dangling pointer. Thank you for a clear explanation. and I didn't added code for a node with two-child case because I was testing with one child and no child.